# Any compound which can react with some unknown calcium compound

Tags: acid-base

I have a body made of steel which needs to be cooled, and it is used tap water to do it and over the time that water has deposited some kind of calcium compound inside the cavity where it's running through and is damaging the cooling process. So I need some compound which could react to the calcium which has been deposited but not with the steel.

Comment: To your title question: yes there is such acid, it is called water. The body of your question contradicts the title, though. Why would you need something that reacts with calcium when you don't have calcium?

Comment: You seem to confuse calcium as element with calcium containing compounds.

Comment: @IvanNeretin sorry, I'll edit the question to clarify this. I have a body made of steel which needs to be cooled, we use tap water to do it and over the time that water has deposited some kind of calcium compound inside the cavity where it's running through and is damaging the cooling process, so I need some compound which could react to the calcium which has been deposited but not with the steel.

Comment: Then try diluted acetic acid.

Comment: @Poutnik yes, I messed up writing the question because the calcium compound is unknown. I was talking with my professor and we're not sure what could be, our bet it's calcium fluoride or hydroxide. Because we're running tap water through a cooling system of a body of steel and that's unknown compound is damaging the cooling process.

Comment: I have wanted to suggest calcium carbonate myself, as Maurice did in the answer.

Comment: There are many lime (CaCO3) deposit removers, some sold commercially for use at home. However, if you have no idea what the compound is, then there can be no definitive answer.

Comment: Is your water supply know to be "hard"? That is - does it contains a high level of Calcium and Magnesium ions?  A commercial kettle descaler will most likely sort this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unknown calcium compound is probably calcium carbonate $\ce{CaCO3}$, which is produced spontaneously when tap water is heated. Tap water contains the ions $\ce{Ca^{2+}}$ and $\ce{HCO3^-}$ which are both slightly soluble in water. When heated the ions $\ce{HCO3^-}$ are decomposed according to $$\ce{2 HCO3^- -> CO3^{2-} + H2O + CO2}$$ And then the ions $\ce{CO3^{2-}}$ react immediately with the calcium ions $\ce{Ca^{2+}}$ present in tap water to produce calcium carbonate $\ce{CaCO3}$, which is insoluble in water $$\ce{Ca^{2+} + CO3^{2-} -> CaCO3}$$

This deposit of $\ce{CaCO3}$ can be removed and dissolved by any dilute acidic solution, like acetic acid, as proposed by Ivan Neretin. The reaction is due to the ion $\ce{H+}$ present in the acidic solution : $$\ce{CaCO3 + 2 H+ -> Ca^{2+} + H2O + CO2}$$

If the acidic solution is diluted, the iron atoms of the steel are not corroded significantly by the $\ce{H+}$ ions of the solution.